# C socket program error

Tags: c, linux, sockets

This is my C client code. Somehow it is not working. It worked when I tried with argument passing.
I want the program to ask user to give `hostname` then it will ask for `portname` and then the message to send:

> Enter hostname: localhost
>   Enter portname: 56456
>   Enter message : Hi user
>   Enter message : What's up
>   Enter message : How are you

And once the host and port given it should not ask for again (until restart the program). I tried with `do while` loop, but it is not working.
On server it will display the sent message

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h> 

void error(const char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(0);
}

//int main(int argc, char *argv[])
int main()
{
    char *argv[256];
    int argc;
    int sockfd, portno, n;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    struct hostent *server;
    printf("\n\nEnter Hostname\n\n");
    fgets(argv[0],256,stdin);
    char buffer[256];
    if (argc < 3) {
       fprintf(stderr,"usage %s hostname port\n", argv[0]);
       exit(0);
    }
    portno = atoi(argv[2]);
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0) 
        error("ERROR opening socket");
    server = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
    if (server == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no such host\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    bcopy((char *)server->h_addr, 
         (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,
         server->h_length);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
    if (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
        error("ERROR connecting");


    printf("Please enter the message: ");
    bzero(buffer,256);
    //buffer = tempFunc();
    fgets(buffer,255,stdin);
    printf("\n\nHere Goes the output\n%s",buffer);
    n = write(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer));
    if (n < 0) 
         error("ERROR writing to socket");
    bzero(buffer,256);
    n = read(sockfd,buffer,255);
    if (n < 0) 
         error("ERROR reading from socket");
    printf("%s\n",buffer);
    close(sockfd);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: The code does not match the given output. Where is the `do while` loop ?

Comment: I deleted this, if you want I will add it

Comment: Have you try using a multiplexor like select, poll or epoll. You should read about that, because simplifies this task a lot.

Comment: @MauroBilotti Don't know about these things. can you please give me some tutorial so that I can try out :)

Comment: You don't want to re-declare `argc` and `argv` within your main, plus `argv` type is not what you want: you should use `char buffer[256]` to get the hostname

Comment: You are aware that you are declaring argv as an array of 256 pointers to char, not a pointer to a 256-element char array right? This issue has been on stackoverflow before, but I don't want to create an answer just for this, so I'll repeat: char *argv[256] is an array of 256 char pointers, char (*argv)[256] is a pointer to a 256-element char array. The way you declare it, argv[0] should be a char pointer to a random location.

Comment: @Coconop I did
 `//char *argv[256];
 //int argc;`
and did
`printf("\n\nEnter Hostname\n\n");
 fgets(buffer,256,stdin);`
Error:

`client.c -o client
client.c: In function ‘main’:
client.c:28:9: error: ‘argc’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     if (argc < 3) {
         ^
client.c:28:9: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
client.c:29:51: error: ‘argv’ undeclared (first use in this function)
        fprintf(stderr,"usage %s hostname port\n", argv[0]);
`

Comment: this is the bible of socket programming. It requieres some effort but is very good explained. http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html

Comment: When reading from and/or writing to a TCP stream **always** check the result of `read()`/`write()` `recv()`/`send()`! Those functions do **not** necessarily transfer the amount of bytes the where told to!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, do not use `char * argv[256]`

```
char buffer[256];
printf("\n\nEnter Hostname\n\n");
fgets(buffer,256,stdin);
```

Then check [Removing trailing newline character from fgets() input](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2693776/3194340) to deal with `fgets`.

For an infinite loop, don't do

```
int a=2; // Useless declaration
do
{
    // Your code
}while(a=2) // I guess you wanted (a == 2)
```

use:

```
while(1)
{
    // Your code
}
```

Or

```
for(;;)
{
    // Your code
}
```

It seems that you need a little bit of training, try some tutorials, look for good practices in `C`, enable warning flags on compilation and learn to use a debugger like `gdb`.

P.S:

- https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking
- https://stackoverflow.com/help/answering

Answer (score 2):

Let's fix some basic things first.
Your `argv` was an array of pointers, pointing to some arbitrary place in memory, here your program could crash.
Next thing is, when you're reading input with `fgets`, you are reading the `\n`, too. So `localhost\n` isn't a valid hostname. Overwrite the last character with an binary zero, to remove the `\n`.

```
int main()
{

    char hostname[256];
    char port[16];
    char buffer[256];
    int sockfd, portno, n;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    struct hostent *server;
    printf("\n\nEnter Hostname\n\n");
    fgets(hostname, 256,stdin);

    hostname[ strlen(hostname) - 1 ] = '\0';
    fgets(port, 16, stdin);
    port[ strlen(port) - 1] = '\0';

    portno = atoi(port);
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0) 
        error("ERROR opening socket");
    server = gethostbyname(hostname);
    if (server == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no such host\n");
    exit(0);
    //...
}
```

Comment: It is working and I added with do while loop that working well

Answer (score 0):

For command line argument you should not declare `argc` and `argv` again! Try this-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>

void error(const char *msg)
{
        perror(msg);
        exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        int sockfd, portno, n;
        struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
        struct hostent *server;
        char buffer[256];
        if (argc < 3) {
                fprintf(stderr,"usage %s hostname port\n", argv[0]);
                exit(0);
        }
        portno = atoi(argv[2]);
        sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        if (sockfd < 0)
                error("ERROR opening socket");
        server = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
        if (server == NULL) {
                fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no such host\n");
                exit(0);
        }
        bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
        serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        bcopy((char *)server->h_addr,
                        (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,
                        server->h_length);
        serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
        if (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
                error("ERROR connecting");


        printf("Please enter the message: ");
        bzero(buffer,256);
        //buffer = tempFunc();
        fgets(buffer,255,stdin);
        printf("\n\nHere Goes the output\n%s",buffer);
        n = write(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer));
        if (n < 0)
                error("ERROR writing to socket");
        bzero(buffer,256);
        n = read(sockfd,buffer,255);
        if (n < 0)
                error("ERROR reading from socket");
        printf("%s\n",buffer);
        close(sockfd);
        return 0;

}
```

and add the do while loop where you want!

Answer (score -1):

Here is the code that works with loop. Thanks to @Coconop

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h> 

void error(const char *msg)
{
    perror(msg);
    exit(0);
}

int main()
{

    char hostname[256];
    char port[16];
    char buffer[256];
    int sockfd, portno, n;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    struct hostent *server;
    printf("\n\nEnter Hostname\n\n");
    fgets(hostname, 256,stdin);

    hostname[ strlen(hostname) - 1 ] = '\0';
    fgets(port, 16, stdin);
    port[ strlen(port) - 1] = '\0';

    portno = atoi(port);
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0) 
        error("ERROR opening socket");
    server = gethostbyname(hostname);
    if (server == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no such host\n");
    exit(0);
    }

bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    bcopy((char *)server->h_addr, 
         (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,
         server->h_length);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
    if (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
        error("ERROR connecting");
int a=2;
do {
    printf("Please enter the message: ");
    bzero(buffer,256);
    //buffer = tempFunc();
    fgets(buffer,255,stdin);
    printf("\n\nHere Goes the output\n%s",buffer);
    n = write(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer));
}while(a=2);
    if (n < 0) 
         error("ERROR writing to socket");
    bzero(buffer,256);
    n = read(sockfd,buffer,255);
    if (n < 0) 
         error("ERROR reading from socket");
    printf("%s\n",buffer);
    close(sockfd);
    return 0;

}
```

---

Comment: If it solved your issue you should accept a proposed answer and delete this one.
Also note that the `do while` loop is useless as `a` is not modified within the loop

Comment: @Coconop I want an infinite loop for that reason I did this and the desired output is correct

Comment: Anyway, you should not post your own answer if it is based on someone's answer, only if it brings something new. To add precision about your question you can `edit` your post. 
Upvote all the answers that helped you solve your problem and accept the more useful.

Comment: @Coconop I have thanked you upvoted you, mentioned you as helping me to do this. Even in my answer and comment I said what I added. I posted it to show as complete answer so that anyone might want it will get it. I didn't edit my problem, and why should I? rather posted as a solution. It is not that I rejected your answer and posted mine as if I am the sole owner of this. I am not getting really logic behind this comment.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I just want to explain you how StackOverflow works. I am grateful you thanked and cited me but on this site you express that by upvote and/or accept, people don't post their fixed code as an answer and they edit their question to precise the problem.
I'm glad we fixed yours and I wish you the best on this site :)

Comment: @Coconop Anyways, I just felt I should contribute back to the community from where I got help :)